# Laravel 5.3 How to show Username in Notifications Email

Tags: laravel, notifications, laravel-5.3, laravel-mail, laravel-notification

I am trying to add the user's first name in the notification emails. At the moment, Laravel notification emails starts like:

```
Hello,
```

And I want to change it to:

```
Hello Donald,
```

Right now, I have a set-up like this. This example is for a Password Reset Notification email:

**User Model:**

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
        {
            $this->notify(new PasswordReset($token));
        }
```

**App\Notifications\PasswordReset:**

```
class PasswordReset extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                    ->action('Notification Action', 'https://laravel.com')
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Is the User Model automatically binded with the Notification Class? How can I add the username in the view?

Comment: now your email send without username?

Comment: yes. It starts with `Hello!` in the notification email which is the default. If I add `$user->first_name` or `$first_name` to the blade, it throws the undefined variable error. So I believe the user object needs to be sent from notification class?

Comment: did you create a mail class for that and a view?

Comment: No. Since it is a notification, I have created the notification class `PasswordReset `.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

> User Model:

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token) {
    return $this->notify(new PasswordReset($token, $this->username));
}
```

> App\Notifications\PasswordReset:

```
class PasswordReset extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public $username;

    public function __construct($token, $username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->greeting('Hello '.$this->username.',')
                    ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                    ->action('Notification Action', 'https://laravel.com')
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }
}
```

Comment: That didnt work. I am getting the error: 
`Argument 1 passed to App\Notifications\PasswordReset::__construct() must be an instance of App\Models\User, string given, called in /app/Models/User.php on line 65 and defined`. This is because the `$token` is passed when calling this Notification class. So when I change to: `public function __construct($token, User $user)`, I am now getting the error `Argument 2 passed to App\Notifications\PasswordReset::__construct() must be an instance of App\Models\User, none given and defined`. It is expecting the User Model to be passed when calling the class.

Comment: That is perfect. Exactly what I was after. This line did it for me `return $this->notify(new PasswordReset($token, $this->username));`. I didn't know I can easily send the user name from the override method in user model directly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @RimonKhan can you explain why this works in the context of the password reset workflow? I don't understand how the User instance is being instantiated or passed looking at the password reset code.

Comment: Oh sorry, never mind. `$this->email` worked for me because my `User` model did not have a `username` property. :)

Comment: `$notifiable` is already passed to `toMail($notifiable)`. That's your user model.

Answer (score 40):

The `$notifiable` variable passed to `toMail()` is User model.

Call to needed User model attribute, easy:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
     return (new MailMessage)
        ->greeting('Hello '. $notifiable->username)
        ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
        ->action('Notification Action', 'https://laravel.com')
        ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to edit `toMail` function in `App\Notifications\PasswordReset` to set `greeting` as you want.

```
public function toMail($notifiable) {
     return (new MailMessage)
        ->greeting('Hello '. $this->username)
        ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
        ->action('Notification Action', 'https://laravel.com')
        ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}
```

**Update**

To set `$username`, have to define a variable & setter method in `App\Notifications\PasswordReset`.

```
protected $username = null;

public function setName($name) {
    $this->username = $name;
}
```

When you initialize `App\Notifications\PasswordReset`, you can set the name.

In `User` model update the function as below.

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token) {
    $resetNotification = new ResetPasswordNotification($token);
    $resetNotification->setName($this->name);

    $this->notify($resetNotification);
}
```

Comment: But that gives the error `Undefined variable: username`. How does the Notification Class get the User details?

Comment: @Neel You have to add a class variable and set it. Updated the answer please check

Comment: Can you show me how do I initialize it in User model?

Comment: @Neel User model is my guess, you may did differently. Do you know where `App\Notifications\PasswordReset` initialized or used in the app?

Comment: As per the docs (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passwords#password-customization) I created a custom Notification class `PasswordReset` and override the `sendPasswordResetNotification` method on the User model (code above). By default the `$token` is passed on to Notification class but not the User Data. In the notification class I was thinking of maybe find the user's name by checking the token in db table and then locate the user using the email address. But that seems like a long way and was wondering if there is an easier way to find the username for this use case. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: @Neel Updated the answer again. Hope this will solve your issue

Comment: @Neel you can use `$this->name` in `User` model.. update the class name according to your code

Comment: Thank you so much. The update was exactly what I was stuck at. @Rimon Khan adding the same answer just now. Sending the user data from the override method in User Model works. It worked without `setname` and I am so happy it works now. I thank you so much for your kind help.