# How do I append the email address to the url when doing password reset in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, laravel-5.3, laravel-mail

I am to append the users email address in the URL when doing password reset, so the reset url would look like this `http://blog.dev/password/reset/4cfbb048346474aab7080c88f16c34b9ea377b9ea35804387216fce303a38855?email=test%40gmail.com`

However I get the error `FatalErrorException in CustomResetPassword.php line 54: Call to undefined method   App\Notifications\CustomResetPassword::getEmailForPasswordReset()`

I am sending the reset email through a custom notification class the code is as follows

```
namespace App\Notifications;


use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;


class CustomResetPassword extends Notification
{
use Queueable;


public $token;



/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($token)
{
    $this->token = $token;

}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail'];
}

/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
     return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject('Reset Password')
        ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
        ->action('Reset Password', url('password/reset', $this->token).'?email='.urlencode($this->getEmailForPasswordReset()))
        ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
}

/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        //
    ];
}
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

`$this` refer to your actual class, you're trying to use `getEmailForPasswordReset` method of `CustomResetPassword` but this method doesn't exist.

You can pass the email to the `notification` as you did for the token.

Comment: I did what you suggested, I passed the email into the constructor public `function __construct($token, $email)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
        $this->$email = $email;
    }` then I called the method `$this->email->getEmailForPasswordReset()` Now I get the error `ErrorException in CustomResetPassword.php line 26:
Missing argument 2 for App\Notifications\CustomResetPassword::__construct(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\app\User.php on line 34 and defined`

Comment: If this solved your issue, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted. It will be nice for anybody else asking the same.

Comment: I wont forget to mark a solution. However the issue is not yet solved

Comment: You edited with the code after my comment. You forgot to pass the email when you call your notification

Comment: Please could you explain how I could do that? Do you mean setting the email variable like `public $email`

Comment: Yes you have to do the same as `$token`, create the property and assign it in the constructor. Can you show me the code that fire this notification?

Comment: Thanks, I've solved it using the ideas here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40703804/laravel-5-3-how-to-show-username-in-notifications-email?rq=1